# How to use Spring boot AutoWired and ScheduledExecutorService?

Tags: spring-boot

I need to use autowired in more than one class with ScheduledExecutorService, what I have tried is shown in this code. logging size of User list in below example always shows 0, even after user added to arraylist. How to properly use Autowired and ScheduledExecutorService in spring boot?

```
@Component
public class AnotherClass {
    List<User> users = new ArrayList();

    public void addUser(User user){
        users.add(user);
    }

    public void logUsers(){
        logger.info("User size " + users.size());  <================= Always logs 0, when called from executor
    }

}

@RestController
public class SecondClass {

    @Autowired
    private AnotherClass anotherClass; 

    @GetMapping(value="/user/test")
    public void logUsers(){
        anotherClass.addUser(new User());
    }
}
```

Application Class

```
@Component
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootDemoApplication {

    private ScheduledExecutorService exec = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

    @Autowired
    private AnotherClass anotherClass; 

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        logger();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootDemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    public void logger(){
        exec.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                try {
                    anotherClass.logUsers();
                }catch (Exception e){
                }
            }
        }, 2000, 1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please read the documentation first: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-task-execution-scheduling

Answer (score 0):

The code works if you use the [Spring](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Autowired.html) `@Autowired` and not the `@AutoWired` Annotation.

Comment: I used @Autowired, it was typo in the example. Not working as expected. `logUsers` called from executor(Not from Controller), and it logs size 0.

Comment: I have YOUR code running on my machine and working as required. `logUsers` Method is called from executor and is increased after every GET request to the endpoint. maybe you could check that the same instance of AnotherClass is injected to your ExecutorService as in your RestController.

Comment: _you could check that the same instance of AnotherClass is injected to your ExecutorService_ that is what I missing. I was creating new Instance somewhere else in program.